# でも in 国民の権利でもあれば、同時に義務でもある

Tags: word-choice, particles

> 選挙権は国民の権利**でも**あれば、同時に義務**でも**ある。

I just came across this sentence in my textbook. I notice that the sentence use "でも" instead of simply "も." What's the difference between "でも" and "も" in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Xでもある and Xもある are different. Xでもある is Xである with も ("also") added after で. Xもある is the same as Xがある but が is replaced by も ("also").

- Xである = is X
- Xでもある = is also X
- Xがある = there is X
- Xもある = there is also X

Compare the following sentences:

- 冷蔵庫にはリンゴ**もあり**、バナナ**もある**。
  In the fridge, there is an apple, and there is a banana, too.
- 彼の好きな食べ物はリンゴ**でもあり**、バナナ**でもある**。
  His favorite food is an apple, and a banana, too.

Here the sentence wants to say "選挙権 **is** 国民の権利 and also 国民の義務", so でもある is the correct option.

(BTW 選挙権は国民の義務である seems to be a wrong opinion to me, but that's another story.)